# Is there any behaviour difference for Request files in laravel api and web?

Tags: php, laravel

I have created similar, but two different Request files for an api controller and web controller. 
I used same middleware for both to change the request parameter.

**Middleware code**

```
$request['size'] = min(20000, 1); 
return $next($request);
```

When I dump, in API request and Web request like following,

```
dd($this->size);
```

the output for API is "20000" and Web is "1". Also, please note that

```
dd($this->request->all());

Outputs :
[
  'size' => "1"
]
```

for both. I want to know how $this->size shows different value in both requests.

Answer (score -1):

```
dd($this->size);
```

it will give you the size of $size variable in class not the value of $request , check whether you have defined size variable in class.

Comment: Isn't $this->size gets set from the request parameter I passed as $this in this context is a Request file

Comment: how can you get size from $this ?

Comment: I am passing POST parameters to 2 controllers. One is for api and other for web. They both uses a Request file for custom validation. "size" is also one of the parameter I have passed as POST. Also note that I am using $this in that Request file. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#form-request-validation

Comment: I have already shared all relevant code in the question itself. What else do you need?

Comment: Complete request file so we can check.